# swfobject.registerObject vs swfobject.embedSWF

Tags: swfobject

swfobject.registerObject vs swfobject.embedSWF. Which one is better and why?

Comment: why do you assume either is better? sometimes there are just alternatives for different situations and without a discussion of your requirements this question is probably meaningless.

Comment: Of course you are right. I just wanted to learn difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`swfobject.registerObject` is used when embedding the SWF using static markup (the nested object approach).

`swfobject.embedSWF` is used for embedding SWFs with JavaScript.

They are not competitors, and are used in completely different circumstances.

References:

[SWFObject documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)

[learnswfobject.com](http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/)